sum without grouping and showing sum only first data
i have data like this



id
no_nota
item
amount
total_amount




1
pos-001
item a
2500



2
pos-001
item b
3100



3
pos-001
item a
2200



4
pos-002
item b
5200



5
pos-002
item a
3300



6
pos-003
item b
4300




and i want result like tis



id
no_nota
item
amount
total_amount




1
pos-001
item a
2500
7800


2
pos-001
item b
3100
-


3
pos-001
item a
2200
-


4
pos-002
item b
5200
8500


5
pos-002
item a
3300
-


6
pos-003
item b
4300
4300



total amount only show in first,pleas help me, thanks

This is more of a formatting the output issue, consider handling this requirement from application / reporting layer, not from sql.

Join the table with a subquery that gets the lowest ID and sum for each no_nota value. Using a LEFT JOIN allows you to substitute - for the rows other than the lowest ID.
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2.total, '-') AS total_amount
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id, SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY no_nota
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id

DEMO
